# Splitting a datafile into multiple, infinite, columns for use in MatPlotLib WITHOUT Pandas

Tags: python, string, split, infinite

I'm very new to Python (Python 3.6 to be exact), and I'm having difficulty with str.split().

I have a .dat file with 11 columns of numbers in several rows (in string format for now) but I need to plot a graph with the data.

The first column of numbers is "x", and the 10 other columns are "Y". I've split files into 2 columns before, but not 11. One of the requisites  was that it needs to be infinitely expandable, and that's what I can't figure out.

So I have so far;

```
#Make Columns Data_X and _Y
data_X=[]
data_Y=[]

#Open file.dat in Python and split columns
file = open('file.data','r')
for line in file.readlines():
data_x,data_y, data_y2, data y3...,data y10 =line.split()
```

Then after this;

```
#Convert string to float
data_X = numpy.array(x, dtype=float)
data_Y = numpy.array(y, dtype=float)
```

This can make the 11 columns, and I can make them floats afterwards for my plot afterwards, but I know this isn't infinitely repeatable (a y12 column will bust it)... and I'm not so sure about the Data_X/Data_Y=[] part either.

How do I split the strings into columns with the potential to do it infinitely? A big stipulation in this is that I can't use pandas either (on top of that, I don't what they do).

Thank you, and I'm sorry if this has been asked a lot but the closest solution I found to my problem was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9459623/splitting-data-file-columns-into-separate-arrays-in-python?newreg=7cbcfc13a0ab4cfa839a8f88c9957fc8), which only brought up one row;

```
for line in file.readlines():
data_X, data_Y = line.split(' ', 1)
```

Comment: `x, *y = line.split()`?  This would give you a single string x and a list of y strings.

Comment: This worked! [Print (x, y)] brought up all the y values, and that means my data_Y=[] part should work too in the graph plotting part, thank you so much!